# How to share values beetwen widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget, that implements an `audioplayers` library and provide button to play/pause audio file and also displays current `position` and `duration` of audio file. Second widget that i have is a `Slider` with a lot of customization so it was defined as a separate widget. All i need to do, is somehow share `position` and `duration` of `AppAudioPlayer` widget between itself and `Slider` and also provide access for `Slider` to audioplayers `AudioPlayer` class `seek()` method to seek the `position` by changing the slider value. I've tried to implement Provider, and GlobalKey, but these task is a bit complicated for this approaches. Also thought about `Stream` to share `position` and `duration`, but doesn't understand how to share instance of `AudioPlayer`. Would love to consider all suggestions!

Comment: Try to simplify your question and be more explicit about what you are asking. In your case, all the audio-stuff is not relevant. What you need to do is share state. Maybe add a simple example. Also explain why Provider is not a good solution? It should work fine for your case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are in need of state management and need to share state between two widgets.

First i would read Flutters overview on [State managment](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt). I would also consider [RiverPod](https://riverpod.dev/), a new and improved state management solution by the creator of [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). Or [Binder](https://pub.dev/packages/binder), a simpler solution, although, not actively maintained ATM.

Although, i think in your case, i would look into using [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) to keep a single state and then [ValueListenablebuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) to listen for state changes. I find this a very simple and pragmatic solution for most cases involving state, and also part of the core Flutter library.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about ValueNotifier too and have recently successful solve my problem with it. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any code hence I have no idea how your code looks like.

If you want to share data between 2 widgets then you can create a global variable and use that variable in both the widgets. Then change the variable accordingly. Now this might not be a solution to your problem but I don't have your code so...

> Also thought about `Stream` to share position and duration, but doesn't understand how to share instance of `AudioPlayer`

I don't think that's how `streams` work. `Streams` are not used for passing data inside your code. You can read about `streams` [here](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)

Comment: A simple global variable is not a good idea for sharing state in Flutter, as this does not update the UI on changes.

Comment: @Erlend I know that but since he didn't provide any code(which I already mentioned in my answer) do expect me to assume his code structure ? No right thats why I gave him a simple solution for now. No need to downvote on that thing, anyways. And I think you we can update the UI on a global variable change

Comment: He basically explained he had two different widgets which need to share state. In order for state to be updated a global variable will not suffice if you need to update the other widget, except if you use a global Riverpod provider which he listens to, but you don't mention anythink like that.